# Javascript add a property with name from string value

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to add a property to a javascript / json object by using a value from a string?

```
let myObj= {};

for{prop in propsToAdd){
    myObj.addProp(prop.name, prop.type);
}

myObj.addProp = function (name, type) {
    // here i need to add another json object 
    // with the name as the name of the property
    // and a property called type with the value of the param type
}
```

example:

```
myObj = {}
myObj.addProb("title","string");
myObj.addProp("id","integer")
```

should result as same as:

```
myObj = {
  "title": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "id": {
    "type": "integer"
  },
}
```

I was thinking of the use of `JSON.stringify` (building strings together) and `JSON.parse`.

But it would be good if there's a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `brackets` notation to add properties to your objects :

```
myObj[name] = {type: type};
```

```js
let myObj = {};

myObj.addProp = (name, type) => {
  myObj[name] = {type: type};
}

myObj.addProp("title", "string");
myObj.addProp("id", "integer");

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Your output is not as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this. Note you probably want `addProp` on both, and not `addProb`:

```js
const myObj = {};
// keep the function from being printed when printing the object
Object.defineProperty(myObj, 'addProp', {
  value: function addProp(key, type) {
    myObj[key] = { type };
  },
  enumerable: false
});
  
myObj.addProp("title","string");
myObj.addProp("id","integer");
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a constructor instead of alter Object prototype :

```
function myObj() {
  this.addProp = function(name, type) {
    this[name] = {type: type};
  }
}

var myVal = new myObj();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myObj.addProp = function (name, type) {
   this[name] = {type: type};
}
```

You can add a property to an object in two different ways.

```
myObj.prop = 'val';
myObj['prop'] = 'val'
```

On the above function, `this` refers to the object you want to add properties to.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let myObj = {};

myObj.addProp = (name, type) =>  {
    myObj[name] = {type: type};
}

myObj.addProp("title","string");
myObj.addProp("id","integer");

delete myObj.addProp;

console.log(myObj);
```